# positive earth clock

Tags: power-supply

Maybe a daft question, but I am not an electronics expert. I have an old car that was originally 12v positive earth. It has been converted to negative earth by a previous owner, and everything works fine, apart from the clock (which has been disconnected and is ok), which is positive earth and is very difficult to convert internally. I understand there is such a thing as an isolated voltage converter that could do this, but cant really get my head round what I want. Would something like [THIS](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/1PB1212S-Powerpax-1W-Unregulated-DC-DC-Converter-1Kv-SIP-12V-In-12V-Out-/351514033101?hash=item51d7de7bcd:g:1JYAAOSwsB9V9ZOX) do, and if so how would I wire it? Many thanks.

Comment: You just need to modify the clock so that you have one GND and one +12V lead to connect to, and then connect it that way to your car without going anywhere to the chassis.

Comment: Can't do that as clock case is metal, and so is dash surround so it is earthed

Comment: What you need is an **isolated** DCDC converter. I cannot determine if the one you link to is isolated, but this one is for sure: http://www.tme.eu/en/details/tme1215s/dcdc-converters/traco-power

Comment: @FakeMoustache isn't the isolation just for show in this case? The metal case will bring the two sides together again. I'd say a non-isolated inverter should work, but maybe I'm just thinking wrong here.

Comment: It has to be isolated.  To make this work, you must connect the positive output of the converter to the vehicle ground.  If it isn't isolated, you get a short circuit.

Comment: @Arsenal What JRE says, basically you need to run the clock from -12 V and that is what you get if you make an isolated 12 V, then connect the positive rail of that 12 V to ground. Then the negative rail will be -12 V (relative to that ground).

Comment: If you showed us photos of where you are finding it difficult to disconnect the clock's metalwork from its circuitry, perhaps we could suggest something simple.

Comment: Many converters thaat meet your need are listed[**HERE** - RS , ISOLATED, 12v IN 12v OUT](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/c/power-supplies-transformers/dc-dc-converters/isolated-dc-dc-converters/?searchTerm=12v+isolated+converter#sort-by=P_breakPrice1&sort-order=asc&esid=4294957161&applied-dimensions=4293610708,4293621950,4293630047,4294847277,4294877116) . Click the ^ under price to get in order of increasing price. Cheapest is GBP3 and 1/4 Watt. At 1/4 W and 12V in you'd get about 15 mA which may be enough. There are many rated at 1 Watt = about 60 mA out from GBP3.20.

Answer (score 2):

Looks promising, but I haven't read the specifications fully. It claims to convert 12v to 12v, with isolation from input to output.

Connect the inputs to the 12v supply from your car. Connect the +ve output to earth, the negative output to the supply input of your clock.

Note that it claims to be 78% efficient, which is presumably measured at 1 watt, which suggests it could consume up to 280mW for itself at that power, probably a bit less at lower output power. This places an extra load on your battery of up to 20mA, or up to 3Ah battery capacity per week. If that extra load is acceptable, then you should be good.

Comment: Small nitpick: 78% efficiency at 1W means 280mW power for the converter.

Comment: @Arsenal was I specifying the 1watt at input or output? OK, yes, it should be output. However I doubt that the 2x0mW loss at 1 watt will be the same at a lower power throughput, and 3Ah per week +/- 1 is not going to make a lot of difference to the decision.

Comment: No you weren't specifying it, but the description of the part says 1W output power, so I assumed you were talking about the same output power. I also doubt there will be a difference for this application. I'm just a bit sensitive when it comes to percent calculation.

Comment: @Arsenal well in my further (lame) defence, I did say I hadn't read the specifications fully. I'll correct the numbers. And I understand sensitivity, I too have burrs under my saddle, just different burrs to yours!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need an isolated converter to do this.

This is what it would look like using an isolated 12V to 12V converter like you posted (simplified):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fX4SRX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But there are also inverting buck-boost converters available which offer no isolation (which isn't needed in this case I dare to say):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxKuuj.png)</sup>

The benefit of non-isolated buck-boost converters is that they can reach higher efficiency than an isolated converter.

The problem might be finding a pre-build unit to do this, as these applications are rather sparse.

Texas Instruments has a small design example available: [Positive 12V to -12V (0.1A) buck-boost converter](http://www.ti.com/tool/pmp7330)

Depending on the current needed by the clock, a much simpler inverting charge pump might also do the trick.

Comment: It looks like you have a DC transformer in the first diagram!

Comment: @Chu yes I do! It's a simplification of an isolated DC-DC converter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Neil, but you are losing me in further comments I'm afraid. Isolated or not isolated? Inverting power pump? The clock apparently takes around 5ma. Just want a simple and cheap solution.

Comment: @RupertSnigg well when you are not in to electronics design and just want a recommendation on which part and how to use it, it's basically off-topic for this site, but the comment of FakeMoustache points to a device from a well known manufacturer (high quality) and Neil_UKs answer provides you with information on how to wire it up. So you can ignore my answer.

Comment: @Arsenal. Thanks for your comment. I would like to learn more about electronics - that is why I came to this site. I have now read up a bit about an inverting power pump and it looks to fit the bill for such a low current usage. I have bought a TC1044S mouser.com/ds/2/268/21348a-29235.pdf and some 1uf capacitors and some strip board and will attempt to make my own supply - you have to start somewhere!

Comment: @RupertSnigg Oh, okay. Sorry for being a bit rude. If you have another question specific to the charge pump, I'd suggest opening another question. Seems like you found a chip which is capable of doing the work.

Answer (score 0):

Many converters that meet your need are listed
[**HERE** - RS , ISOLATED, 12v IN 12v OUT](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/c/power-supplies-transformers/dc-dc-converters/isolated-dc-dc-converters/?searchTerm=12v+isolated+converter#sort-by=P_breakPrice1&sort-order=asc&esid=4294957161&applied-dimensions=4293610708,4293621950,4293630047,4294847277,4294877116).

You say load ~= 5 mA.
At 5 mA clock power is nominally about 5 mA x 12 V = 60 mW.
Allow say 100 mW input power minimum. More does no harm.

Click the ^ under price to get in order of increasing price.
Cheapest is GBP3 and 1/4 Watt. At 1/4 W and 12V in you'd get about 15 mA which may be enough. There are many rated at 1 Watt = about 60 mA out from GBP3.20.

Connection (generic) is

Vin+ - postive 12v.
Vin - - ground

Vout + - ground
Vout - - clock -ve input.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBl8Ge.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>